# Silverlight UI Automation of a TextBlock

Tags: silverlight-3.0, textblock, ui-automation

I'm trying to set up UI automation for Silverlight 3.  I have a little test project that has 2 elements, a Button and a TextBlock.  When you click the button the text is supposed to change.

I have been able to simulate a button click and the text does correctly change on the UI.  However I am having problems retrieving the text from the TextBlock.  UISpy shows that it is of type "text" but it also shows that it implements no control patterns.  If I use a TextBox I can get the text correctly using a ValuePattern, but I would prefer to use TextBlock.

Does anyone know how to get the current text of a TextBlock from it's AutomationElement object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextBlock` exposes its text as the Name property of the automation element, so you can read the text from `myTextBlockAutomationElement.Current.Name`.

Comment: TextBlock does show up in the control view.  I have no problem getting the AutomationElement but from there I can not get at the text.  With a TextBox you can check the ValuePattern and get it's text but that doesn't work with a TextBlock.  What I need is a way to get the actual text from a TextBlock.

Comment: Sorry - I was writing from memory. I'll check how I've actually done it. :)

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it.  I actually just found that.  The caveat I'll specify is that you can't supply a name property.  You must identify items using AutomationProperties.AutomationId and not AutomationProperties.Name.  As long as it doesn't have a name it will work great.  Thanks for your help.